# Two factor Authentication in ASP.NET WebForms and FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, authentication

I am enhancing the security of existing application by adding two factor authentication. At present user enter credentials on logon page and if they are valid, user can access the rest of the application pages. Now In order to implement two factor authentication I have developed `EnterAdditionalInfo.aspx` page which will be presented after validating credentials on logon.aspx page.If information is valid user will be able to access rest of the application pages. My problem is if i don't  call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, False)` before  Response.Redirect(("~/EnterAdditonalInfo.aspx")) then I cannot access `EnterAddtionalInfo.aspx` and if I call it then user is already authenticated which fails two factor authentication.  If I do the following settings in web.config
`<location path="EnterAdditionalInfo.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>`
then any one can bypass the logon page and access the second page which I don't want as it will open the doors for brute force attack. I would be grateful if anyone could help to guide me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you want two factor authentication? Can you not use some kind of Role management in order to allow specific user access to specific pages?

Comment: @MightyLampshade. Thanks for reply. We already have role management and some of pages are already protected. This is a special requirement from some of our clients who wants this feature like banks and other financial type of Applications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by creating some session variables to hold key information from logon page and if they are empty when the EnterAdditionalInfo page is loaded it will take the user back to logon page and in that case they cannot bypass the logon page. FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie will be called after the user has passed all the credentials check.